# Newtonsoft json DeserializeObject with DefaultValueHandling not working with runtime object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, default-value, json-deserialization

I'm trying to have a property of an object to return a default value in the absence of that property in the json I deserialize.

I read that I can achieve this using the `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]` attribute.

```
    public class MyClass {
        public readonly string Id;
        [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
        public RectangleF Position { get; set; } = new RectangleF(0, 0, 1, 1);

        [JsonConstructor]
        public MyClass(string id, RectangleF position) {
            Id = id;
            Position = position;
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void DeserializeDefaultValue() {
        var json = JObject.FromObject(new { id = "123" });
        var obj = json.ToObject<MyClass>();
        Expect(obj.Position, Is.EqualTo(new RectangleF(0, 0, 1, 1)));
    }
```

The test fails, with the position always returning a `new RectangleF(0, 0, 0, 0)`

I can't have a `[DefaultValue]` attribute, like I see in a lot of examples, since RectangleF is initialized at runtime.

I tried many things such as having the `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]` in the constructor, overloading the constructor with a default value for position, but nothing works.

Is there something simple I'm missing to achieve this?

Comment: Try to use `DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`.`DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate` initialize your property with it's `Type` default value if `DefaultValue` is not set.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: When you set `DefaultValueHandling` to `DefaultValueHandling.Populate` the `Serializer` first is looking if there is `DefaultValue` attribute for that property, than if it isn't there just give default value to the property. For example if the property is `int` it will give it `0`.

Comment: Yeah I get that. In this case the default value for RectangleF is `new RectangleF(0, 0, 0, 0)`. But I'm looking for a way for it to default to `new RectangleF(0, 0, 1, 1)` when it's not specified in the json.

Comment: `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` should live the value that you set in runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I modified what you were doing slightly but this works for what you are trying to accomplish.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public readonly string Id;
    public RectangleF Position { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public MyClass(string id, RectangleF? position)
    {
        Id = id;
        Position = position ?? new RectangleF(0, 0, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Just to add to this, if the only contractor you have assigns any value to a property, the property initializer is ignored (always).  If you add a default constructor (with no params) then I believe what you have above will always work.

Comment: Yes, It is a Struct

Comment: I made the RectangleR Nullable in the params for the constructor.  I quickly ran this in code and it did work.

Comment: No worries mate.